# Camel case in web resources

Tags: java, url, naming-conventions

What is you opinion on using camel case for web resources?

I am coming from a Java background where camel case is second nature, but still when naming web resources, such as html, css, javascript camel case does not feel right.

(e.g. http://localhost/application/editUserForm.html vs http://localhost/application/edit/user/form.html)

Any comments, suggestions are welcome!

Comment: This is an entirely subjective matter. As such, (a) there is no answer, and (b) it belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main consideration on naming schemes would be impact on SEO.  From my understanding, Google (and presumably other engines) can 'read' amalgamated words in a single string, so camel case should be OK, as would a single case-insensitive string.  Splitting the scheme by directory using rewrites would be clearer for less capable spiders.  One piece of advice Google give is to use hyphens (-) rather than underscores (_), but that's not relevant here.

If you expect a real person to ever have to type the full address, using something easy to read would be a bonus in order to minimise error.

Comment: Indeed you are right, but the question obviously was not clear enough. I was more concerned on the style than the functional part of the url name.  The resources I am talking about are mostly hidden from the public web and contain dynamic content, so google discovery and indexing are not an issue. Point taken though!

Comment: You final sentence was right to the point! "If you expect a real person to ever have to type the full address, using something easy to read would be a bonus in order to minimise error".

Answer (score 1):

I don't find anything wrong with such naming.

My personal preference is to name web resources with `-`, like `edit-user.jsp`. I think it's more question of personal taste. I don't like `_`. `-` makes easier to visually find separate words in browser address bar (at least for me). And as far as I saw `-` is pretty common.

Answer (score 1):

It might open the door to problems with 2 the same resources that differ in casing, if you are deploying your site on a windows environment (either for development or hosting).

But if you avoid 'double' filenames like that it's more or less taste.

A naming-scheme like this `http://localhost/application/edit/user/form.htm` does show the seperate words better, and might be easier to parse as something to do with "user".

Answer (score 1):

I don't find camel casing very appealing. While it is the convention for Java and we should follow it when doing java, we don't have to when naming other stuff.

It's not that we find it tedious inserting a separator between every two words, but the underscore is really hard to type, it requires two pinky fingers to stretch very far. Unfortunately underscore is favored by language designers in identifiers.

Whoever invent the next programming language, please use '/' as name space separator, and '.' as word separator, so instead of

```
java.beans.beancontext.BeanContext.getResourceAsStream()
```

we have

```
java/beans/bean.context/Bean.Context/get.resource.as.stream()
```

wait... '/' is already used for division. never mind.